# Alternative to Email Piping

Tags: php, web-hosting, email

I am developing a webapp that lets you update your account by sending a simple text email, then it sends a simple email back confirming it. This was working fine at my previous host, who had cPanel with email piping.

Since then, I've moved to dreamhost, particularly because lifehacker rated it #1 and gave an incredible discount. I've found them great so far. But then when I tried to transfer over the email piping feature they told me they do not support email piping. The only thing they support is [Forwarding mail to a shell account](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Shell-linked_E-mail) which requires you to upgrade to a VPS anyway.

So what alternatives do I have? The only thing I can think of is having a cronjob executed every 5 seconds that checks an email account via POP/IMAP, but (1) that sounds quite intensive on the server to have that running every 5 seconds, and (2) from the sounds of that wiki article and what support has told me, I think that is what requires a VPS account anyway...

Help!

Comment: THe user sends information from his own email client or directly from the site ( form?) I'm not quite sure I understand you but apparently the user sends a specifically formated email to update some fields and you used to retrieve this email with email piping, and update the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option, a service that consumes email and posts to a form of your choosing:

http://blog.webhooks.org/2009/02/13/restful-email-over-http/

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I can think of is having a cronjob executed every 5 seconds

Cron jobs can't be processed more than once a minute, and doing this once a minute doesn't sound *two* horrible, assuming that you aren't doing any intensive processing when importing the email.

If you're stuck on shared hosting, then this is probably as good as it's going to get.